# Why does NSLocale.current.identifier include currency on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

If I request the current locales identifier on iOS, it returns just the identifier string:

```
let identifier = NSLocale.current.identifier // en_GB
```

However, on macOS 10.12.2 it also returns the currency:

```
let identifier = NSLocale.current.identifier // en_GB@currency=GBP
```

Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: Is there a more appropriate way to the identifier like `en_GB`, `en_US`?

Comment: I'm not seeing this on macOS 10.12.2. Are you sure that System Preferences > Language & Region > Region pop-up menu says "United Kingdom" and not "United Kingdom (Custom)" or something like that? If you click the Advanced button at the bottom of the window, is Restore Defaults enabled? If you click it and re-test, is the issue still there?

Comment: Interesting. It was set to `United Kingom (Custom)`. However this has made me rethink my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option for me here is to generate the code myself. To help with this I have created an extension on `Locale`:

```
extension Locale {
    var iso3166code: String {
        guard
            let language = languageCode,
            let region = regionCode
            else { return "en-US" }
        return "\(language)-\(region)"
    }
}
```

While this is accurate enough for my purposes, you should probably ensure it returns expected values for your project.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently. I'm not sure why, but apparently as of 10.12, `localeIdentifier` [can include a bunch of stuff besides country and language](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1416263-localeidentifier?language=objc).

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't elaborate on the cases in which other metadata is included.

However, also as of 10.12, there's another property [`languageCode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1643026-languagecode?language=objc), which, in conjunction with [`countryCode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1643060-countrycode?language=objc), you can use to generate `en_US`.

This is what [iTerm2 does](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/79aff4d59fd591e7628649bcabe5f27541740bf6/sources/PTYSession.m#L7090).